# Spring configuration metadata Map missing description

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm using the following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

I have the following configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "example")
public class MyProperty {

 /**
 * myVariable documentation.
 */
private Map<String, Integer> myVariable;


 /**
 * myVariable2 documentation.
 */
private String myVariable2;
```

My generated spring-configuration-metadata.json

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "type": "java.lang.String",
  "description": "myVariable2 documentation.",
  "sourceType": "path.MyProperty"
},
{
  "name": "example",
  "type": "java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>",
  "sourceType": "path.MyProperty"
}
```

For the Map the description is missing. Any ideas why?

Comment: Try adding a period (.) at the end of the description as `myVariable documentation.`

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work